# Flatten an XML string into an SQL table using dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, xml-parsing, dynamic-sql, sql-server-2017

I am trying to figure out how to convert or flatten an XML string with custom attributes into a flat SQL table.

Here's a sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<affidavitsResponse>
  <isFinal>false</isFinal>
  <opportunitiesPresent>false</opportunitiesPresent>
  <summary>
    <unit>
      <impressions>11405</impressions>
      <clicks>0</clicks>
      <clickThroughRate>0.0</clickThroughRate>
      <stationId>230293</stationId>
      <stationName>QUB_RADIO</stationName>
      <campaignShortDetails>
        <campaignId>3331851</campaignId>
        <campaignVariant>ADVERTISING</campaignVariant>
        <campaignName>Partenariat QUB</campaignName>
      </campaignShortDetails>
      <flightId>9311461</flightId>
      <flightName>LIVE STREAM</flightName>
      <adId>14773721</adId>
      <adName>Ad #14773721</adName>
      <creativeId>10375741</creativeId>
      <creativeName>NISSAN GABRIEL - EVENEMENT LA CEST NISSAN V2 - DOMINIC - 2019 JUILLET 12[2]_3 (10375741)</creativeName>
    </unit>
    <unit>
      <impressions>59457</impressions>
      <clicks>0</clicks>
      <clickThroughRate>0.0</clickThroughRate>
      <stationId>230293</stationId>
      <stationName>QUB_RADIO</stationName>
      <campaignShortDetails>
        <campaignId>3331851</campaignId>
        <campaignVariant>ADVERTISING</campaignVariant>
        <campaignName>Partenariat QUB</campaignName>
      </campaignShortDetails>
      <flightId>9311461</flightId>
      <flightName>LIVE STREAM</flightName>
      <adId>14773721</adId>
      <adName>Ad #14773721</adName>
      <creativeId>10498051</creativeId>
      <creativeName>GROUPE NISSAN GABRIEL - LA REFERENCE 15 SEC INOUT - DOMINIC - 2019 AVRIL 19 (1)_5aout (10498051)</creativeName>
    </unit>
  </summary>
  <totals>
    <totalsByTrafficType>
      <total>
        <impressions>382329</impressions>
        <clicks>0</clicks>
        <clickThroughRate>0.0</clickThroughRate>
        <trafficType>INSTREAM_SPOT_CPM</trafficType>
      </total>
      <total>
        <impressions>678640</impressions>
        <clicks>0</clicks>
        <clickThroughRate>0.0</clickThroughRate>
        <trafficType>PODCAST_PREROLL_CPM</trafficType>
      </total>
    </totalsByTrafficType>
    <totalsByDaypart>
      <total>
        <impressions>1060969</impressions>
        <clicks>0</clicks>
        <clickThroughRate>0.0</clickThroughRate>
        <daypartId>29</daypartId>
      </total>
    </totalsByDaypart>
    <impressionTotals>
      <impressions>1060969</impressions>
      <clicks>0</clicks>
      <clickThroughRate>0.0</clickThroughRate>
      <name>Grand Total</name>
    </impressionTotals>
    <spotTotals>
      <name>Grand Total</name>
    </spotTotals>
    <grandTotal>
      <impressions>1060969</impressions>
      <clicks>0</clicks>
      <clickThroughRate>0.0</clickThroughRate>
      <name>Grand Total</name>
    </grandTotal>
  </totals>
  <impressionDetails>
    <detail>
      <impressions>56</impressions>
      <clicks>0</clicks>
      <clickThroughRate>0.0</clickThroughRate>
      <stationId>256633</stationId>
      <stationName>OMNY_AHAUTEVOIX_P</stationName>
      <campaignShortDetails>
        <campaignId>3331851</campaignId>
        <campaignVariant>ADVERTISING</campaignVariant>
        <campaignName>Partenariat QUB</campaignName>
      </campaignShortDetails>
      <flightId>9311471</flightId>
      <flightName>AUDIO RATTRAPAGE</flightName>
      <adId>14773731</adId>
      <adName>Ad #14773731</adName>
      <creativeId>9497551</creativeId>
      <creativeName>* NISSAN GABRIEL - 30 SEC GENERAL MARS 2019 - 2019 MARS 18 (9497551)</creativeName>
      <creativeInformation>MP3, 31s</creativeInformation>
      <daypartId>29</daypartId>
      <datePlayed>2019-03-19 00:00:00.000 -0400</datePlayed>
      <trafficType>PODCAST_PREROLL_CPM</trafficType>
    </detail>
  </impressionDetails>
  <spotDetails/>
  <request>
    <userId>163823</userId>
    <reportingRequestType>FULL</reportingRequestType>
    <startDate>2018-10-01</startDate>
    <endDate>2019-08-27</endDate>
    <flightTypeFilter>PAID_ONLY</flightTypeFilter>
    <affidavitsType>BY_CAMPAIGN</affidavitsType>
    <affidavitsGranularity>DAILY</affidavitsGranularity>
    <affidavitsParameters>
      <entityType>CAMPAIGN</entityType>
      <entityId>3331851</entityId>
      <entityName>Partenariat QUB</entityName>
    </affidavitsParameters>
    <includeSyncedBannerImpressions>false</includeSyncedBannerImpressions>
    <includeIsciCodeData>false</includeIsciCodeData>
    <includeSongData>false</includeSongData>
  </request>
</affidavitsResponse>
```

I'm trying to create a flat table with all columns and their respective values.  Here is what I've achieved thus far, but I'm a bit green when it comes to all the navigating hierarchies technicalities in XML tree nodes:

```
DECLARE @file NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'C:\Users\Win2K16\Desktop\affidavits.xml'
DECLARE @xml XML
DECLARE @results table (result XML)
DECLARE @sqlstmt NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sqlstmt= 'SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET ( BULK ''' + @file + ''', SINGLE_CLOB) AS xmlData'

INSERT INTO @results EXEC (@sqlstmt)
SELECT @xml = result FROM @results

--build an XML object with the unique list of nodes
DECLARE @xmlcolumns XML;
WITH Xml_CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        CAST('<' + node.value('fn:local-name(.)',
            'varchar(100)') + '>' AS varchar(100) ) 
         + CAST('</' + node.value('fn:local-name(.)',
            'varchar(100)') + '>' AS varchar(100) ) AS name 
    FROM @xml.nodes('/root/item/*') AS roots(node)

)

SELECT @xmlcolumns = (
SELECT CONVERT(XML,name) FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT name 
FROM Xml_CTE
) a
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('root')
)

declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''
declare @Col nvarchar(max) = ', T.N.value(''[COLNAME][1]'', ''varchar(100)'') as [COLNAME]'  

--use the unique column list xml object to build the select statement
select @SQL = @SQL + replace(@Col, '[COLNAME]', T.N.value('local-name(.)', 'sysname'))
from @xmlcolumns.nodes('/root/*') as T(N) 

--build the entire query statement, using the original XML object as the data source
set @SQL = 'select '+stuff(@SQL, 1, 2, '')+' from @xml.nodes(''/root/item'') as T(N)' 

exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@xml xml', @xml;
```

The code above was originally given by @Mikael Eriksson and subsequently modified by @RussellZ.

Ideally, I would need something mostly dynamic and as generic as possible to be able to parse any kind of custom well-formed XML structure and output a series of columns into a flattened SQL table structure.

Using SQL Server 2017.